# System directories not owned by root after preseed install 18.04.2

Tags: preseed

I have an issue where there are no files owned by root after an unattended install using preseed on Ubuntu 18.04.2.  I discovered this when I could not use sudo.  Upon investigation, I found that /usr, /lib and /home were owned by 1001:1001, not root, and the same for any files or sub-directories.  This wasn't a problem in the past, so I'm a bit mystified.  Please see my preseed file below:

```
# Localization
d-i debian-installer/locale             string  en_US.UTF-8
d-i debian-installer/language           string  en
d-i debian-installer/country            string US

# Keyboard layout
d-i console-setup/ask_detect            boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/layoutcode   string  us
d-i keyboard-configuration/charmap      select  UTF-8
d-i keyboard-configuration/layout       string English (US)


### Network configuration
d-i netcfg/choose_interface             select auto
d-i netcfg/use_autoconfig               boolean true
d-i netcfg/get_domain                   string cg.chrysler.com

### Mirror settings
d-i mirror/country                      string  manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname                string  us.archive.ubuntu.com
d-i mirror/http/directory               string  /ubuntu
d-i mirror/http/proxy                   string  
d-i proxy                               string  
d-i mirror/protocol                     string  http

### Account setup
d-i passwd/user-fullname                string ictadmin
d-i passwd/username                     string ictadmin
d-i passwd/user-password                password chrysler1
d-i passwd/user-password-again          password chrysler1
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home             boolean false

### Clock and time zone setup - TS verified ntp server 
d-i clock-setup/utc                     boolean true
d-i time/zone                           string  America/Detroit
d-i clock-setup/ntp                     boolean false
d-i clock-setup/ntp-server             string  ntp.example.com 

# Automatically detect device name of install disk
d-i partman/early_command   string      debconf-set partman-auto/disk /dev/"$(fdisk -l |grep -i linux | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d / -f 3 |sed 's/p[0-9]$//p' |head -n1)"

### Partitioning and disk encryption
d-i partman-auto/method                 string  crypto
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase             password 
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase-again       password 

d-i partman-lvm/purge_lv_from_device    boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm       boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md         boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm                boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite    boolean true
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe          select  atomic

d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition            select finish
d-i partman/confirm                     boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite    boolean true

### Package selection
tasksel tasksel/first                   multiselect ubuntu-desktop
ubiquity    ubiquity/keep-installed string icedtea6-plugin openoffice.org
# Enable extras.ubuntu.com.
d-i apt-setup/extras    boolean true
d-i pkgsel/include/install-recommends   boolean true

### Boot loader installation
d-i grub-installer/only_debian          boolean true##  TO DO:  Resolve how to create more file systems
##  Need to have OS separated from data
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os        boolean true



### Copy and install some extra stuff

### When ubiquity/success_command is invoked /target is mounted

ubiquity ubiquity/success_command       string \
   in-target apt purge gdm3 ; \
   in-target apt update ; \
   in-target apt-get -y install net-tools libwebkitgtk-3.0 terminator gdm3 ; \
   in-target hostname `echo "ubn"$(lshw | grep -m 1 serial | awk '{print tolower ($2)}')` ; \
   hostname > /target/etc/hostname ; \
   sed -i "2s/.*/127.0.1.1\t$(cat /target/etc/hostname)/" /target/etc/hosts

ubiquity ubiquity/use_nonfree   boolean true
ubiquity ubiquity/reboot   boolean  true
```

Comment: If you're wanting to see the username for 1001, try `cat /etc/passwd|grep 1001` . Usually the name isnt listed if that user has been deleted. As for why it did this, I honestly am not even sure what preseed is so not the best person to answer this. I would be very interested to find out though.

Comment: I did that.  Normally, if a file or directory isn't owned by a user the system recognizes it gives it a made-up  UID:GID.

Preseeding is a way of doing an unattended install.  The lines in the preseed file answer all the questions that you would normally face in an Ubuntu installation.  It's really nice when it works!